# Formatting date in tornado template

Tags: tornado

I and to display a date in a tornado template.

This date comes from main program as template parameter

{{ mydate }}

I want to format this date. I don't want to display hour.

How should i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful feature of Tornado's template system is that the template variables are treated as Python objects and therefore you can call their methods directly in the templates.

To format a datetime object, you can call it's [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method to format the date:

```
{{ mydate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}

# will output 21-03-2018
```

---

Since you mention that the date comes from your database as a string, in that case you'll first have to convert that to a Python datetime object using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strptime).

```
from datetime import datetime 

datetime.strptime("2018-03-21 10:38 PM", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
                   \_________________/    \_______________/
                            |                     |
                       date from db   <- format of the given date
```

Comment: I have tried before posting my question. It does not work. Maybe this is because the date comes from database (pymysql). Is there a way to cast and force datatype of mydate to datetime ? Thanks

Comment: @Bob5421 You can use `datetime.strptime` to convert a string to a Python datetime object. I've updated the answer.